# break from .each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i break from jquery each with out `return FALSE`.

consider the following

```
function check_quantity(){

  var _q = $(".quantity");

       _q.each( function(){

           if( some_condition ){

             break; // I WANT TO BREAK HERE AND NEED TO RETURN A TRUE INSTEAD OF FALSE
                    // for some reasons there is no way to continue 
           }

        } );

   return FALSE; // if condition failed

}
```

is there any work around ?

Comment: can't you just do if( some_condition ){ return true;} ?

Comment: [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) makes it pretty clear that returning something other than `false` is equivalent to `continue`, and `return false` is equivalent to `break`.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you used a [`while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) instead?

Comment: @Mottie actually there were no loops , but after some time the requirment is changed and i am forced to use loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your function, just set a flag to true in your loop if you get what you want in it.

```
function check_quantity(){

  var ret = false;
  var _q = $(".quantity");

       _q.each( function(){

           if( some_condition ){

             ret = true; // I WANT TO BREAK HERE AND NEED TO RETURN A TRUE INSTEAD OF FALSE
                    // for some reasons there is no way to continue 
           }

        } );

   return ret; // if condition failed

}
```

Comment: yes , i got it,i also added a `return FALSE` after `ret = true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep continue'ing. So, just don't do anything:

```
q.each(function () {
    if(condition) {
      //don't do anything
    }
    else {
      //do stuff
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you wouldn't just `return false` in order to break, though.

Comment: change in requirment ,this function is used almost all page in my project and the expected return value is `TRUE` instead of `FALSE`.

Comment: You only need to return false in the function you pass to q.each, not the function where you call q.each